# Recover a NPM package

Tags: npm

I recently published a package on NPM and my system crashed before I backup.

I have re-installed node & NPM and now want to update my package. My question is can I simply install my package from NPM to become the owner or do I need to re-create a module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It may be more suitable for [ubuntu.se] or [su].

Answer (score 0):

If you succeeded in publishing a package, then you *are* the owner.

Do an `npm login` and continue developing.